# how to ranking csv file in netlogo

Tags: csv, netlogo, rank

I have a csv file

It contains a set of values, and I try to rank you for these values , as in Excel(n competition ranking, items that compare equal receive the same ranking number, and then a gap is left in the ranking numbers. The number of ranking numbers that are left out in this gap is one less than the number of items that compared equal. Equivalently, each item's ranking number is 1 plus the number of items ranked above it. This ranking strategy is frequently adopted for competitions, as it means that if two (or more) competitors tie for a position in the ranking, the position of all those ranked below them is unaffected (i.e., a competitor only comes second if exactly one person scores better than them, third if exactly two people score better than them, fourth if exactly three people score better than them, etc.).

Thus if A ranks ahead of B and C (which compare equal) which are both ranked ahead of D, then A gets ranking number 1 ("first"), B gets ranking number 2 ("joint second"), C also gets ranking number 2 ("joint second") and D gets ranking number 4 ("fourth").

```
Set ranking[0] to 1.
For each index i in the score-list
    If score[i] equals score[i-1] they should have same ranknig:
        ranking[i] = ranknig[i-1]
    else the ranking should equal the current index:
        ranking[i] = i + 1
        (+ 1 due to 0-based indecies and 1-based ranking)
```

and I tried some code to do
'`    extensions [csv]
      globals [data variable]
      turtles-own [var ]

```
   to setup
   file-close-all
     file-open "test1.csv"
    ;; read the data all at once by using csv:from-file
    set data csv:from-file "test1.csv"
    reset-ticks
    end

    to ranking
      if file-at-end? [stop]
      ;; extract value from the list, using item 0 to remove the list, and just keep the value
      set variable item 0 item ticks data


        if ticks = length data [stop]

        let rank-list sort-on [variable] turtles
        let ranks n-values length rank-list [  ]
        (foreach rank-list ranks [ask ?1 [set variable 2] ] )
        tick

       ;show variable
       end`
```

but I did not succeed with Netlogo (6.1)

Comment: You say "I did not succeed". Did you get an error message, other unexpected behavior, or what? If there was an error message, what was it?

Comment: I am a beginner in the netlogo, so there is a mistake in the code @SethTisue

Comment: Did you get an error message? If so, what was it?

Comment: _ let ranks n-values length rank-list [ ? ]  "nothing named ? has been defined "    i used  netlogo (6.1)

Comment: The `?` syntax is old NetLogo 5 stuff. NetLogo 6 syntax is different; see https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/transition.html#changes-for-netlogo-60